# Base change of galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K\leq L$ be a any field extension(It can be transcendental extension)

Let $\alpha_1,...\alpha_n $ be elements in $\overline L $ such that $L\leq L(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)$ is galois extension.

Assume that $\alpha_1,...\alpha_n\notin L$ and $\alpha_1,...\alpha_n\in \overline K$

Can we say that $K\leq K(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)$ is galois??

Actually, original statement deal with $K=\mathbb{Q}(t), L=\mathbb{C}(t) $ where $t$ is any transcendental element over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: No. For the general case, take $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=K(e^{2i\pi/p})$, $n=1$ and $\alpha_1=p^{1/p}$ where $p \geq 3$ is a prime. For the original case, take $n=1$, $\alpha_1=t^{1/p}$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you very much!